# Error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and I'm having a problem with the compilation of my code.

This is the error message: 
app/car-parts.component.ts(17,27): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Code:

**car-parts.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CarPart } from './car-part';
import { RacingDataService } from './racing-data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'car-parts',
    templateUrl: 'app/car-parts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/css/car-parts.component.css']
})
export class CarPartsComponent{
    carParts: CarPart[];

    constructor(private racingDataService: RacingDataService){}

    // ngOnInit is invoked after the component is constructed
    ngOnInit(){
        let racingDataService = new RacingDataService();
//      this.carParts = racingDataService.getCarParts();
        this.racingDataService.getCarParts().subscribe(carParts => this.carParts = carParts);
    }
    getTotalCarParts(){
        let sum = 0;
        if(Array.isArray(this.carParts)){
            for(let carPart of this.carParts){
                sum += carPart.inStock;
            }
        }
        return sum;
//       return this.carParts.reduce((prev,curr) => prev + curr.inStock,0);
    }
    upQuantity(carPart){
        if(carPart.quantity < carPart.inStock)
            carPart.quantity++;
        else{
            alert("The ordered quantity exeeded the stocks");
        }
    }
    downQuantity(carPart){
        if(carPart.quantity > 0)
            carPart.quantity--;
    }
}
```

**racing-data.service.ts**

```
import { CARPARTS } from './mock';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CarPart } from './car-part';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RacingDataService{

    constructor(private http: Http){

    }

    getCarParts(){
        return this.http.get('app/car-parts.json').map(response =>  <CarPart[]>response.json().data );
//      return CARPARTS
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add `service` in **providers**:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  providers: [RacingDataService]
})
```

Then remove line:

```
let racingDataService = new RacingDataService();
```

from `ngOnInit()`.

It should be like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.racingDataService.getCarParts().subscribe(carParts => this.carParts = carParts);
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I am not sure, then you have to check that your component is loading or not? Console `this.carParts` in  `.subscribe()`.  and use `error => <any> error` in `subscribe()` and see what you are getting?

Comment: My problem is now solved. I forgot to include app.module.ts in the question. The problem is that I put HttpModule in declarations inside @NgModule. Thank you for your answer in ngOnInit() part.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar error for this Angular app: *Error: Can't resolve all parameters for CarPartsComponent: (?)*. This helped me:

**car-parts.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CarPart } from './car-part';
import { RacingDataService } from './racing-data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'car-parts',
  templateUrl: './car-parts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-parts.component.css']
})
export class CarPartsComponent {
  carParts: CarPart[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.carParts = this.racingDataService.getCarParts();
  }

  constructor(private racingDataService: RacingDataService) {}
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RacingDataService } from './racing-data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [RacingDataService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Welcome to racing';
}
```